# How to find out by what method the steel was made, having a microstructure?

Tags: metal, materials

I know that rolled steel will have grains elongated in the rolling direction and I don't see anything similar in the microstructures of these steels. If I'm not mistaken, then the irregular boundaries between the crystals means that they are randomly arranged.
I am also knowledgeable that extrinsic microstructural features such as entrapped refractory inclusions, aluminum oxide films, and porosity are not common in modern, commercially processed.
With that in mind, I think these microstructure patterns belong to forged rather than rolled steels. Do you agree with me? Do you see any other features that are characteristic of forged or rolled steel?

**1.Ferrite,several oblong and globular slag inclusions can be seen.**
[image]

**2. Ferrite only.[image]**

**3. Pearlite abd ferrite.**
[image]

**4. Ferrite,pearlite,and slag.**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Interesting micrographs of steel destroyed in high temperature service. It is a wrought steel (elongate inclusions) but not much other information available in the deteriorated condition. Chemistry will give some info, other than carbon which has been changed in service. Looks like exposure approximately in the range of 1100 F to get decarburization and creep/stress rupture. Some subsequent carburization around the rupture in Fig. 3. I have not seen microstructure like this since I retired long ago, memories.